# Oracle query won't compile

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm a bit confused. Can anyone tell me why this won't compile?

```
declare
varSampleCode varchar2(80);
varResult integer;

varFilterString varchar2(80);

begin

varSampleCode := 'sam001';
varFilterString := 'somecolumn=2'; 

execute immediate  'select CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 1 from samples where samplecode = :varSamplecode  and auditflag = 0 and ' || varFilterString || ') then 1 else 0 end  into :varResult from DUAL'
using IN varSampleCode, OUT varResult;
```

end;

Assume the variables are all declared and the query itself makes sense. I get this error report:
Error report:
ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 12
01006. 00000 -  "bind variable does not exist"

Comment: It's not a duplicate, because the other question doesn't provide the answer.

Comment: Yes it does, use `out` in your bind variables if you're using an INTO statement within the execute immediate. However, if it doesn't solve your issue please read the documentation and provide a _complete_ minimal example that demonstrates your issue - as it is we've no idea what code you're actually running.

Comment: Okay, example changed to a complete code fragment that uses an OUT keyword but still will not compile. The point is not that it won't execute correctly, but it won't (in Sql Developer) even compile.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the dynamic statement you are trying in your `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is a SQL statement, not a PL/SQL statement. And `INTO` is not SQL, it is PL/SQL.

You can either do a dynamic **SQL** statement with just one bind variable and then place your `INTO` outside the dynamic statement. This is supported when doing a dynamic **SQL** statement:

```
execute immediate  'select CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 1 from samples where samplecode = :varSamplecode  and auditflag = 0 and ' || varFilterString || ') then 1 else 0 end from DUAL'
into varResult 
using IN varSampleCode;
```

Or you can do a dynamic **PL/SQL** anonymous block:

```
execute immediate  'begin select CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 1 from samples where samplecode = :varSamplecode  and auditflag = 0 and ' || varFilterString || ') then 1 else 0 end into :varresult from DUAL; end;'
using IN varSampleCode, OUT varResult;
```

This time the `INTO` must be inside the dynamic string and using a bind variable, because with the `BEGIN` and `END;` you are now doing dynamic **PL/SQL**.

For your use case I'd recommend the first option, doing dynamic **SQL** and placing the `INTO` *after* the statement string.

Comment: Aha, I see the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344486/oracle-pl-sql-query-does-not-compile . In *that* question you actually have figured out that the `INTO` is supposed to be outside the dynamic string. It would have been nice to close this question then, as you already had the answer to this one ;-)

Comment: in that question is also problem with `varResult integer;` instead `integer` should be `number` or `pls_integer` or `simple_integer`...

Comment: Why, @Franek ? `integer` is simply a subtype defined as `number(38,0)` - what is the problem with using `integer` for this?