# Oracle PL/SQL query does not compile

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can anyone tell me why this won't compile? I get a 'missing expression' error:

```
execute immediate  'select CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 1 from samples where samplecode = :samplecode  and auditflag = 0 and ' || varFilterString || ') then 1 else 0 end  from DUAL'
into varResult
using varSampleCode;
```

Assume the variables are all correctly declared.

TIA

Comment: Check your varFilterString , it may be malformed. Specifically it might be Null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle query won't compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343913/oracle-query-wont-compile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
execute immediate  'select  count(1) from DUAL
                      where EXISTS
                       ( SELECT 1 from samples
                        where samplecode = :sample code
                          and auditflag = 0 
                          and ' || varFilterString || ')'
into varResult
using varSampleCode;
```